# TeX on iPad compatible with Apple's policy?

Tags: ipad, latex, tex

As a nerd, I think it would be nice to have a TeX editor on the iPad. But TeX is a Turing-complete language, and it is arguably a general-purpose compiler/interpreter. Does that make it unacceptable to the App Store? Furthermore, if somebody ports TeX compiler to javascript and runs inside WebKit, does it make acceptable to the App Store?

FYI, here's the section of the developer's agreement:

> 3.3.2 An Application may not itself install or launch other executable code by any means, including without limitation through the use of a plug-in architecture, calling other frameworks, other APIs or otherwise. No interpreted code may be downloaded and used in an Application except for code that is interpreted and run by Apple's Published APIs and builtin interpreter(s).

**Update** (Jun.11.2010) Apple changed the section as follows:

> 3.3.2 Unless otherwise approved by Apple in writing, no interpreted code may be downloaded or used in an Application except for code that is interpreted and run by Apple’s Documented APIs and built-in interpreter(s). Notwithstanding the foregoing, with Apple’s prior written consent, an Application may use embedded interpreted code in a limited way if such use is solely for providing minor features or functionality that are consistent with the intended and advertised purpose of the Application.

which might open the way to having TeX on iPad.

**Another Update** (Sep.10.2010) Apple caved in to the outside pressure (maybe the antitrust investigation?)

> 3.3.2 An Application may not download or install executable code. Interpreted code may only be used in an Application if all scripts, code and interpreters are packaged in the Application and not downloaded. The only exception to the foregoing is scripts and code downloaded and run by Apple’s built-in WebKit framework.

I guess now it's perfectly OK to have TeX on iPad. Who is going to port a TeX distribution?

Answer (score 1):

You might try using [LaTeX Lab](http://code.google.com/p/latex-lab/), which integrates with Google Docs and allows you to created/edit LaTeX documents in your Google Docs space. As to whether you could implement TeX/LaTeX on the iPhone/iPad, you'd have to ask Apple, as they are the final arbiters, and their decisions are not always straightforward.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the link to LaTeX Lab. Alas it's not a javascript implementation of TeX...

Answer (score 0):

Given that TeX is ultimately an interpreted language, TeX on the iPad is probably a non-starter. Even if you could have a TeX interpreter app, the support files for TeX for a full distribution run to several GiB.

Comment: Yeah... maybe I should make one just for my own use. Basic TeX installation can be made below 100MB, too. I used TeX 15 years ago on a DOS box with 640K memory!

Comment: I was thinking more of all the macro packages. But you can indeed make TeX fit in a small space.

Comment: Yes I knew you referred to the macro packages... but many of the elderly colleagues of mine don't even know the existence of a full distribution of TeX, and lives without problem using a very old, small installation of TeX on his/her PC.

Comment: Good for them, I'm personally fond of my significantly larger TeX install.

Comment: @Hackworth, you have the best nick ever :)